# Cannot see changes I made on php file

Tags: php, html, caching

If I edit an html file on my website, save it and refresh the page I can immediately see the changes. Yet, the same does not happen when I am working on php files. How come?

Is cache the magical word here? If yes, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: What types of changes are you making that you cannot see? It is possible you wrapped something in a conditional and are just not seeing that 'path'

Comment: Hate to ask, but you remembered to upload modified files if the server is remote, right?

Comment: It could well be a cache thing, find out how to clear the page/entire cache for your browser of your choice and see if it helps.

Comment: @JustinWood No conditionals; it happens even if everything I am doing is a print("Hello World 2").

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yep. :)

Comment: @DBS I would rather not to cancel cache every time I make some changes.

Comment: @AnnoysParrot Just make your change, clear the cache, and see if that allows you to see your changes. It would just be a test to see if it is something aggressively caching.

Comment: @JustinWood Ok, I tried to open the page with another browser (which I have never used) and the page was still showing the old code. So I guess it is not a problem with the cache of the broswer.

Comment: Maybe your server has APC cache which cache php script for some time. Edit your file and wait 5 minute without refreshing any page.

Comment: @MbRostami I erased a file around 30 minutes ago. It still shows.